# QGIS 3.14: new attribute sorting feature

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sorting

The 3.14 Changelog includes this new feature:

"[Allow sorting attribute table by field not listed in the table](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-allow-sorting-attribute-table-by-field-not-listed-in-the-table)"

The description states: "Instead of using the same data model for the displayed and the sorting columns, two data models are now used. They use the same API / base class as they are very similar."

This new feature sounds intriguing, but I don't understand what the changelog is saying, nor can I find any other help on the web.

When and how would I use this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with you the explanation in the help is unclear. It seems you can sort the table in the Print composer by adding an expression in QGIS 3.14, whether the table comes from CSV table or feature class. This feature does not exist in QGIS 3.10.

The following image shows where you could find the feature. In QGIS 3.10 you can sort a table by adding field with green plus and the table will be sorted based on that field.

[image]

In QGIS 3.14 an expression was added to sort a field by combining two fields or any other expression as you like, which is an enhancement added in QGIS 3.14.

[image]

I hope I am not mistaken, but this is what I found when I compared the two versions of QGIS.

**Update**

In the following example the sort is based on y-coordinates `$y` in descending order which is a field not listed in the table:

Before sorting:

[image]

After sorting based on `$y` in descending order:

[image]

Comment: The confusing part of the tool's description is"... field not listed in the table."  Your example (which was very informative) uses fields that ***are*** listed in the table: Ip and Jp.

Comment: @StuSmith I agree the help didn't describe it clearly, but it seems you can add an expression to sort based on y-coordinates `$y`, for example, which is a field not listed in the table. I updated my answer to show it visually.

Comment: Ahah!  That makes sense, thanks.